# laptop keybord not working

Tags: keyboard, touchpad

i have hp laptop and it frequently looses keyboard and touchpad. most of the time it works fine after simple reboot but this time it didn't work. i tried reinstalling the distro but now only touchpad works. I need help with my keyboard not working. i tried various solution but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I did encounter this issue with my gaming laptop (GA401QM). The roots of cause vary due to diffferent possibilities. Here I list them from the most severe one to the least with possible solutions.

1. Hardware failure. -> You need to change the motherboard (in my case)
2. Fail to upgrade the firmware. -> Need to do a factory-reset and re-install everything.
3. Driver issue. -> update your OS.

Mine got failure after the upgrade **of the windows partition**. I went to the service center of the laptop and discussed this situation. I did try to re-install the whole laptop from *factory reset* but it helped nothing. However, it turn out to be the hardward failure and thus I got it repaired by warrenty in the repairing center.